# Grouping sql result with linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a sql result like as follow:

```
SehirID uniKodu
34      014
34      014
34      014
34      014
41      176
999     176
46      070
38      070
```

and i need a dictionary as

```
 Dictionary<uniKodu, Dictionary<SehirID, sumofSehirIDs>>
```

it refers to

```
unikodu sehirId count
014      34     4     
070      46     1      
070      38     1 
176      999    1
176      41     1
```

how can i do that with linq? Any suggestions?

Comment: Your desired result is invalid since a dictionary's key must be unique. `70` and `176` are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired result is invalid since a dictionary's key must be unique. `70` and `176` are not unique. But you could use a similar collection created by [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var uniKoduLookup = db.Table.ToLookup(x => x.uniKodu);
```

If you now want to know the `sehirID`s of `uniKodu=14` and their counts you do:

```
var uniKodu14 = uniKoduLookup[14];  // returns an empty sequence if it isn't contained
int count = uniKodu14.Count();
List<int> sehirIDs = uniKoduLookup.Select(x=> sehirId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//From the Database (assuming something like this)
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 1).Select(i => new { SehirId = 1, uniKodu =1 });

var dict = result
    .GroupBy(r => r.uniKodu)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(r => r.SehirId, g.Sum(r => r.SehirId)));
```

Comment: You will need to group the inner groupings by `SehirId` as well (and do a `Count` instead of a `Sum`).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var dict = result
    .GroupBy(o => new {o.SehirID, o.uniKodu})
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key.uniKodu, 
        g => g.ToDictionary(
            r => r.SehirId, 
            r => g.Count(r.SehirId)
        )
    );
```